# Get all information from an SGML DTD in Perl

Tags: perl, sgml

I would like to get information from an SGML DTD (element, attribute, etc.) I tried to get the element with the help of module use SGML::DTD, which is not working. Suppose, if the DTD contains duplicate elements with distinct attribute, I get an element as only one time.

I tried this: `@allelements=$dtd->get_elements(0);`

Are there any other modules I can use to retrieve the values from SGML DTD and SGML parser?

Comment: Can you add some examples of input and output? Why do you expect an element to be different to the same element, if it has a different attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Another module which may work is SGML-DTDParse:

- [SGML-DTDParse](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SGML-DTDParse/bin/dtdparse)